hyva checkout and mollie payment combination
I have installed hyva / hyva onestep checkout and mollie + mollie/magento2-hyva-checkout so hyva compatibility extension.
The design still shows up as old hyva onestep checkout instead of more beautiful mollie .
what could be an issue?

I asked that question in hyva slack, turns out that design shown on mollie website is for marketing purpose.
